# CASE Clause in SELECT Statement. Correct Formatting Question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to display a custom (right term?) column (a column not present in the tables I'm drawing from) called myPercentage in this query I'm writing, but I think I'm getting the formatting of the CASE clause incorrect:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.lastDate, A.Numerator, A.Denominator
    ,(CASE
            WHEN (A.Numerator<>'0' AND A.Denominator='0') THEN '100%'
            WHEN (A.Numerator='0' AND A.Denominator<>'0') THEN '0%'
            WHEN (A.Numerator='0' AND A.Denominator='0') THEN '0%'
            ELSE (A.Numerator / A.Denominator)
    END) AS myPercentage
FROM Sample_Table_A AS A INNER JOIN Sample_Table_B AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
WHERE A.lastDate='1975-01-15'
```

The fields A.Numerator and B.Denominator are both of the value type money in the table.

I'm getting the follow error

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

I'm guessing it's because I'm not formatting my query correctly.  Whitespace, commas, semicolons, that type of stuff.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: which rdms are you using postgres?

Comment: My apologies! I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You're mixing strings and numeric datatypes. SQL is both strongly and statically typed. If your numerator and denominator are numeric values, compare them to numeric values, not the string `'0'`. Likewise, your case expression returns strings in some places and the result of a division otherwise. Don't do that, the expression can only return one type. I recommend returning a numeric value, not a string with a `%` character; SQL is for data, not presentation to humans. If your report, application, etc, need to format a value as a percentage, have that layer do it, not your data layer.

Comment: `WHEN (A.Numerator='0' AND A.Denominator<>'0') THEN '0%'` you can omit that since the result of numerator/denominator will be 0 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `CAST` the money column into a numeric number

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Sample_Table_A(ID int,Numerator money,Denominator money ,lastDate date)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Sample_Table_B(ID int)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT A.ID, A.lastDate, A.Numerator, A.Denominator
>     ,(CASE
>             WHEN (A.Numerator<>'0' AND A.Denominator='0') THEN '100%'
>             WHEN (A.Numerator='0' AND A.Denominator<>'0') THEN '0%'
>             WHEN (A.Numerator='0' AND A.Denominator='0') THEN '0%'
>             ELSE (CAST(A.Numerator AS real)/ CAST(A.Denominator AS real))
>     END) AS myPercentage
> FROM Sample_Table_A AS A INNER JOIN Sample_Table_B AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
> WHERE A.lastDate='1975-01-15'
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | lastDate | Numerator | Denominator | myPercentage
> -: | :------- | --------: | ----------: | -----------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4692f219a79b999344a320f46064bedb)*

Comment: You commented on my answer (which I've deleted because it seems you know something about this OP's problem that I don't see) about `cascading 20 or more cases would become a nightmare` - what cases are those specifically, and how does your answer account for them?

Comment: there are two Money columns, and we don't know the rules, he wants to use, he asks only about the else clause, so it could get complicated, but you don't need to delete your answer, it was only my opinion about cascading without knowing the depth, maybe it is as simple, but his doubling of zero suggest a somewhat more extensive case statement

Comment: I don't know, seemed like a simple percentage calculation between two columns, and I'm not sure what other columns you could introduce (or if there _were_ 18 other columns how your answer would address them without a similar nightmare).

Answer (score 1):

Every branch of a [`CASE` expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) must be able to return a value in a data type compatible with (and of the highest [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) across) all branches. It's not possible to convert a string like `100%` to a type compatible with a numeric expression like `5/10`. Your query should probably be something like this:

```
SELECT A.ID, 
    CASE WHEN A.Denominator = 0 THEN
      CASE WHEN A.Numerator = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 100 END
         WHEN A.Numerator   = 0 THEN 0 
         ELSE (100 * A.Numerator / A.Denominator) END AS MyPercentage
         FROM dbo.Sample_Table_A AS A
         INNER JOIN dbo.Sample_Table_B AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
         WHERE A.lastDate = '19750115';
```

Then if you want to put `%` characters on it, format it to n decimal places, etc., do that at the presentation layer. If you have to do it in T-SQL, just do it *after* the `CASE` expression is processed:

```
;WITH MakePretty AS
(
  SELECT A.ID, 
    CASE WHEN A.Denominator = 0 THEN
      CASE WHEN A.Numerator = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 100 END
         WHEN A.Numerator   = 0 THEN 0 
         ELSE (100 * A.Numerator / A.Denominator) END AS MyPercentage
         FROM dbo.Sample_Table_A AS A
         INNER JOIN dbo.Sample_Table_B AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
         WHERE A.lastDate = '19750115'
)
SELECT ID, MyPercentage = CONCAT(CONVERT(decimal(5,2), MyPercentage),'%')
  FROM MakePretty;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b7a8658c4bb2305e9ae276493aa5b64)

Comment: i think it is only a sample and so cascading 20 or more cases would become a nightmare